# ActiveJDBC: integer[] on PostgreSQL with multiple schemas in one DB

Tags: java, postgresql, activejdbc, javalite

I am trying to use `ActiveJDBC` to properly convert an `integer[]` from my `PostgreSQL` database into the java `equivalent int[]`.  I get the fetch done properly, but the object that is returned is `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array_org_postgresql_jdbc_PgArray`.  I have yet to find a way to convert that.

I have tried 2 different ways of accessing the data:

First, using the standard `record.findFirst("id = ?", id)` format.  Because I have multiple schemas in my database, I added the `@Table` notation to my Model.

Second, I tried doing a `record.findBySQL("select array from record where id = ?", id)`.  I also tried `array::integer[]`.

Each time I get back the PgArray type.  I have searched for a way to convert this type into something else for use, but nothing has worked.

Is there a way to do this?  Do I need to use a different way of data retrieval other than `ActiveJDBC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html) defines `java.sql.Array` to handle array typed columns. `PgArray` is just the Postgres implementation of `java.sql.Array`.

Given the array object `a` you can call `(Integer[])a.getArray()` to get an `Integer` array from the JDBC array object (if the JDBC driver has decided that it will return you `Integer` objects and not some other `Numbers`). A helper method to extract the value and convert to `int[]` would probably be a good idea.

Don't know if activejdbc has support to do this conversion behind the scenes.

Comment: I am unable to use the getArray() method.  ActiveJDBC places all retrieved items into my Model and I retrieve them using: model.get("column").  There is no getArray() method associated with that.

I have tried casting that to both Integer[] as well as PgArray, but both throw ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: I just found that solution on another post here.  It worked successfully.  Thanks!

Comment: when you get the array by calling `get("column")`, what Java type are you getting back?

Comment: @ipolevoy The class returned was `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array_org_postgresql_jdbc_PgArray`